# Programmatically disable portrait orientation lock

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

In my camera app, everything works perfectly fine orientation wise. If portrait orientation lock is not enabled on a users phone, then everything works perfectly.

However, if a user has portrait orientation lock enabled and they record sideways, then the video gets recorded in portrait mode but everything is sideways inside the video.

Is there any way to check if portrait orientation lock is enabled or any way to get around this? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things. You can override the `shouldAutorotate` function in the view controller that you are using the camera in like so:

`override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
   return true
}`

Then you could set it to false again once they are finished with the camera so it retains their device settings. Not sure if this is the best way, but is A way.

Another possible way that you might be able to get around this is to simply always check the device orientation. The device will still detect the physical orientation of the device even if the visual orientation of the UI doesn't autorotate (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620053-orientation). So the following shows the possible device orientations, as per the Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation)

`enum UIDeviceOrientation : Int {
    case Unknown
    case Portrait // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
    case PortraitUpsideDown // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
    case LandscapeLeft // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
    case LandscapeRight // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
    case FaceUp // Device oriented flat, face up
    case FaceDown // Device oriented flat, face down
}`

Knowing those you can just check if the current orientation is one of those:

`if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
     UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft) {
            ...override autorotate to true
}`

These might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable portrait orientation lock by using this method:

```
- (NSUInteger)lockorientation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: where and how do i implement this. It tells me expected decleration?